# How to call c# function from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is a shared database on the server and multiple clients connect to it. Every client has a table that shows database items.

If one of the client deletes a record from the table, then other client must be aware and their tables being updated (live table).

How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [SqlDependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SQL Server Service Broker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893.aspx).

Comment: Note that SqlDependency does not scale well to multiple clients. If you plan on having a large number of connected clients you should write a service that runs on the server and listens for the SqlDependancy and when it gets notified it then goes and notifies the waiting clients using some other form of inter-machine communication.